# TypeScript getter sometimes observed by Vue, other times not

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to understand how/when Vue re-renders an element.

Consider the grid below:

[image]

You can see that the total hours for Steve Rogers was updated to 9 hours (after filling the saturday cell) but the total for saturday is 0 hours.

Both of these values come from typescript getters:

```
class ScheduledEmployee {

    Id: number;
    Name: string;

    get TotalHours(): number {
        let total = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.ScheduledDays.length; i++) {
            total = total + this.ScheduledDays[i].TotalHours;
        }
        return total;
    }

    ScheduledDays: ScheduledDay[] = [];
}
```

and

```
class ScheduleDate {
    Date: Date;
    Id: number; //id is ticks at midnight
    Day: string;
    ParentSchedulerVM: SchedulerVM;

    //a cross-employee index of the schedule for this day (vs by employee)
    // - for quicker totaling and coverage calculation
    ScheduledDays: ScheduledDay[] = [];

    get TotalHours():number {
        let total: number = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i++; i < this.ScheduledDays.length) {
            total += this.ScheduledDays[i].TotalHours;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

I do realize I'm pushing the bounds of what the Vue's simple data prop is supposed to be.  **However, i would still like to know the possible reasons why one of those getters is being pulled from with no problem, and another is not working.**

Answer (score 0):

Meh, this turned out to be a simple bug.  Note in the second for loop that I somehow managed to swap the test with the incrementer.  Vue is working just fine :P.